# Kendo ui mobile create dynamic body height for iPhone 4 & 5?

Tags: html, iphone, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

Kendo mobile ui create dynamic body height for iphone 4, 4s, 5 etc.. Please find the code below

Tested in ripple emulator (iPhone 5)

```
<body class="km-on-ios km-ios km-ios5 km-5 km-m0 km-web km-pane km-vertical" data-  
role="pane" style="height: 628px;">
```

Tested in ripple emulator (iPhone 4/4s)

```
<body class="km-on-ios km-ios km-ios3 km-3 km-m0 km-web km-pane km-vertical" data-
role="pane" style="height: 540px;">
```

Please help me how to remove the dynamic height

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a way of fixing it so I ended fixing it with this solution:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
        $('#documentBody').attr('style', 'height:100%');
});
```

May be not the most elegant but it works

Answer (score 0):

I used css for that:

```
.km-on-ios{
    height: 100% !important;
}
```